# How to populated WPF comboboxes with generic enum to List<string> function

Tags: wpf, generics, enums, valueconverter

I would like to populate WPF combobox (and other similar controls) with the geniric `enum` to `List<string>` below:

**How do I call it in XAML?**

```
public class ToList<TEnum> : List<string> where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    public static ToList()
    {
        foreach (TEnum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)))
        {
            // Skips some values (TEnum.NotDefined)
            if (e.Equals((TEnum)Enum.ToObject(typeof(TEnum), -1))) continue;
            
            // GetDescription() is an extension method based on the [Description] attribute
            Add(e.GetDescription());
        }
     }
}
```

*Example with hardcoded enum*

XAML with `MyEnum` a property of the view model

```
<converters:MyEnumToStringConverter x:Key="MyEnumToString"/>
...
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyEnumList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyEnum, Converter=MyEnumToString}">
```

Non-generic enum-to-List method

```
public class MyEnumList : List<string>
{
    public MyEnumList()
    {
        foreach (MyEnum myEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
        {
            if (myEnum == myEnum.NotDefined) continue;

            Add(myEnum.GetDescription());
        }
    }   
}
```

Value converter (with culture localization potentially  in the future). **Can I pass the enum as targetType or parameter?**

```
public class MyEnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => ((MyEnum)value).GetDescription();

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => Binding.DoNothing;
}
```

Basically, I don't want to hard-code the example above for `MyEnumA`, `MyEnumB` and so on.

Thanks for any insights :-)

Comment: You can check [the following post](https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-bind-an-enum-to-a-combobox-in-wpf.htm). It uses a MarkupExtension to provide values (support localization using `[DisplayAttribute]`). The [working sample is available on GitHub](https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Framework/tree/a540fa401aaf3b68574f1cc6258b7f3708e875c9/Samples/Meziantou.Framework.WPF.EnumComboBox)

Comment: OK thanks, but I'll still wait a bit for localization. I slighltly modified the `ToList<TEnum>` class. If I can write something like that (constructor) in the viewmodel public `MyEnumList() => new ToList<MyEnum>();` with no extra lines, I'll be entirely pleased.. is there a notation hack here? (I read somewhere that XAML doesn't support generics anyway).

Comment: Derive ToList_TEnum : ToList<TEnum> {} and then you can refer to ToList_TEnum in XAML